# Console operator in java is not able to compile

Tags: java, eclipse

Below is just an example of a java program using console operator and the program should be able to compile fine, but for some reason, my eclipse is not able to read "Console"
operator? please Help!.

```
public class Dot_operator {
public static void main (String [] args){
 String name3 = Console.readLine("hello");
        System.out.println(name3);
 }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to import the class from some third party library.

Comment: You didn't close the bracket behind the args

Answer (score 1):

[`Console#readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readLine%28%29) is an instance method. You would need an instance of `Console` to invoke it.

```
Console console = System.console();
String name3 = console.readLine("hello");
System.out.println(name3);
```

Of course, you would need to import `java.io.Console`. Note that, this will thrown a `NPE` when run on eclipse, as [`System.console()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29) will give you `null`. You should better use `Scanner` class here.

Comment: yes, the console get resolved but I get and Exceptional error in thread main, The program itself is working fine that i have posted, it just for some reason, My machine is not able to resolved operator  " Console" , I have heard about cleaning the Eclipse environment something, But i don't know how to do that.

Comment: @User101 First of all `Console` is a class, not operator. What do you mean by not resolved. What happens when you hit `Ctrl+Space` after moving the cursor at the end of `Console`?

Comment: Alright, When, I press Ctrl+space next to console class comes up nothing else?,"Concole.class"

Comment: Not next to `console`, but `Console`? Try adding an `import java.io.Console` to your source file. And then clean and build your project.

Answer (score 0):

You probably made a simple typo: you didn't close the bracket next to the args:

```
public class Dot_operator {
public static void main (String [] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("hello");
   String name3 = sc.nextLine();
   System.out.println(name3);
 }
}
```

This works on my machine.

Comment: Yes, it works on my other machine, but for some reason, It doesn't seem to resolved it in this machine.